# XSLT 2.0 get distinct nodes names and preserve order

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to transform `XML` to `CSV` where each entry does not contain all values. The column order must be preserved.

Initial file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
   <entry>
      <a>FR</a>
      <b>Dupont</b>
      <c>123456</c>
      <d>zzz</d>
      <f>New York</f>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <a>FR</a>
      <b>Martin</b>
      <c>234561</c>
      <d>xxx</d>
      <e>2019-01-01</e>
      <f>Paris</f>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <a>FR</a>
      <b>Chris</b>
      <c>345612</c>
      <d>yyy</d>
      <e>2019-01-01</e>
   </entry>
</data>
```

Expected output:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f
FR;Dupont;123456;zzz;;New York
FR;Martin;234561;xxx;2019-01-01;Paris
FR;Chris;345612;yyy;2019-01-01;
```

I am struggling with getting the header values in the correct order. I tried `distinct-values()` and `for-each-group()` but I am not able to preserve the order.

One example of what I tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all">  

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//entry/*/local-name())">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
abcdfe
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Seems very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059964/finding-nodes-from-xslvariable-in-xslfor-each/59060418#59060418

Comment: You say you're having trouble getting the output in the correct order but you don't say what the correct order is. In your example the input and the output are both alphabetical: is that just a feature of your example, or will it always be true?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (updated):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="cols" as="element()*">
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//entry/*/local-name())">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
            <Item><xsl:value-of select="."/></Item>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,';')"/> 
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="//entry">
        <xsl:variable name="entry" select="."/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat($entry/*[local-name() = current()], ';')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="cols" 
     as="xs:string*" 
     select="let $max-cols := max(data/entry/count(*))
             return distinct-values(data/entry[count(*) = $max-cols]/*/local-name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:value-of select="$cols" separator=";"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="for $col in $cols
                return string(*[local-name() = $col])" 
        separator=";"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5Em/1